# UWP Handle Tapped and Click events in a different way

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a button inside a `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"
               Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
    <Button Name="btnTagDelete"
            Holding="btnTagDelete_Holding"                                 
            PointerReleased="btnTagDelete_PointerReleased" 
            Tapped="btnTagDelete_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to handle the behavior of `btnTagDelete` button differently on a touch screen device and a device with a mouse connected. I thought of using `Tapped` and `Click` event. But the `Tapped` event always takes precedence over the `Click` event ie, `Tapped` event is fired on a mouse click as well as on a tap.
Same with `PointerPressed` and `PointerReleased`. How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the Tapped event and check the event args in your handler. PointerDeviceType will tell you where the "tap" came from.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.input.pointerdevicetype